# Why does my bounding boxes show for some images and not for others?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, bounding-box

I am trying to plot my bounding boxes through my pretrained model with the help of this keras tutorial (for the evaluation of the model section): https://keras.io/examples/vision/object_detection_using_vision_transformer/#evaluate-the-model. The issue I am facing is with the same code as per the tutorial, some of my images show the bounding boxes while some others do not.

My code:

```py
model_load = load_model('stenosis_model_transfer.h5')
# To calculate IoU (intersection over union, given two bounding boxes)
# To calculate IoU (intersection over union, given two bounding boxes)
def bounding_box_intersection_over_union(box_predicted, box_truth):
    # get (x, y) coordinates of intersection of bounding boxes
    top_x_intersect = max(box_predicted[0], box_truth[0])
    top_y_intersect = max(box_predicted[1], box_truth[1])
    bottom_x_intersect = min(box_predicted[2], box_truth[2])
    bottom_y_intersect = min(box_predicted[3], box_truth[3])

    # calculate area of the intersection bb (bounding box)
    intersection_area = max(0, bottom_x_intersect - top_x_intersect + 1) * max(
        0, bottom_y_intersect - top_y_intersect + 1
    )

    # calculate area of the prediction bb and ground-truth bb
    box_predicted_area = (box_predicted[2] - box_predicted[0] + 1) * (
        box_predicted[3] - box_predicted[1] + 1
    )
    box_truth_area = (box_truth[2] - box_truth[0] + 1) * (
        box_truth[3] - box_truth[1] + 1
    )

    # calculate intersection over union by taking intersection
    # area and dividing it by the sum of predicted bb and ground truth
    # bb areas subtracted by  the interesection area

    # return ioU
    return intersection_area / float(
        box_predicted_area + box_truth_area - intersection_area
    )


i, mean_iou = 0, 0

# Compare results for 10 images in the test set
for input_image in test_images[:5]:
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 15))
    im = input_image
    plt.tight_layout()

    # Display the image
    ax1.imshow(im.astype("uint8"))
    ax2.imshow(im.astype("uint8"))

    input_image = cv2.resize(
        input_image, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA
    )
    input_image = np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0)
    preds = model_load.predict(input_image)[0]

    (h, w) = (im).shape[0:2]

    top_left_x, top_left_y = int(preds[0] * w), int(preds[1] * h)

    bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y = int(preds[2] * w), int(preds[3] * h)

    box_predicted = [top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y]
    # Create the bounding box
    rect = patches.Rectangle(
        (top_left_x, top_left_y),
        bottom_right_x - top_left_x,
        bottom_right_y - top_left_y,
        facecolor="none",
        edgecolor="red",
        linewidth=1,
    )
    # Add the bounding box to the image
    ax1.add_patch(rect)
    ax1.set_xlabel(
        "Predicted: "
        + str(top_left_x)
        + ", "
        + str(top_left_y)
        + ", "
        + str(bottom_right_x)
        + ", "
        + str(bottom_right_y)
    )

    top_left_x, top_left_y = int(test_targets[i][0] * w), int(test_targets[i][1] * h)

    bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y = int(test_targets[i][2] * w), int(test_targets[i][3] * h)

    box_truth = top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y

    mean_iou += bounding_box_intersection_over_union(box_predicted, box_truth)
    # Create the bounding box
    rect = patches.Rectangle(
        (top_left_x, top_left_y),
        bottom_right_x - top_left_x,
        bottom_right_y - top_left_y,
        facecolor="none",
        edgecolor="red",
        linewidth=1,
    )
    # Add the bounding box to the image
    ax2.add_patch(rect)
    ax2.set_xlabel(
        "Target: "
        + str(top_left_x)
        + ", "
        + str(top_left_y)
        + ", "
        + str(bottom_right_x)
        + ", "
        + str(bottom_right_y)
        + "\n"
        + "IoU"
        + str(bounding_box_intersection_over_union(box_predicted, box_truth))
    )
    i = i + 1

# print("mean_iou: " + str(mean_iou / len(test_images[:10])))
plt.show()
```

As mentioned earlier, the code is the same from the keras tutorial.

**I am well aware that the images are shown as black, just did not want to show the image. Just need to change the datatype.**

The predicted labels are shown as well but no bounding boxes on either side of the image for comparison while another image shows the bounding boxes clearly.
The results:
[image]

[image]

Hope my issue is clear. Would appreciate any help for this code snippet.

Comment: [mre] please... your pictures (as shown in the plots) appear entirely empty

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have not made the image visible, I know they are shown in black. But I was just facing the issue with the bounding boxes and have made a few changes for the code in the ```ax1``` and ```ax2.imshow(im, extent=[0,500,0,500])``` functions. I have added extent feature to get the image to fit in the plot. However, my bounding boxes do not seem to be accurate due to the extent feature.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your plot range is limited to include up to 224 pixels, while your bbox coordination points are way over 224 (`323` precisely, refer to the bottom `Predicted:` values). Increasing plot range (x axis) could be a solution.

The image you are testing with (which is not showing bbox) is larger than the one you tested earlier.

Comment: Oh okay so you mean the x and y scales? I just added `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim` after `plt.tight_layout()` to increase the plot range but there was a lot of white space remaining in the plot and it only changes the image size on the right.